# Range at the end of the line chart

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

Is it possible to put a range at the right side of the line chart to compare the distance between the last 2 points of the 2 lines?

[image]

Comment: Natively it's not possible, also there isn't any chart.js plugin available.. as to my knowledge. However you can draw it yourself, if you have any experience on HTML5 Canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved via a custom plugin making [direct draw calls to the canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D), an example of which I've included below. Note that the code makes *a lot* of assumptions based on your screenshot and should be considered as a starting point rather than a perfect drop-in solution.

```js
let myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Group1',
      data: [-1000, -2000, -2000, -3000, -4000, -3000, -5000],
      backgroundColor: '#F48496'
    }, {
      label: 'Group2',
      data: [-4000, -4000, -3000, -6000, -6000, -5000, -9000],
      backgroundColor: '#61B2E9'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    layout: {
      padding: {
        right: 100
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  plugins: {
    afterRender: function(c) {
      let
        // calculate difference between values of last two points in first and second datasets.
        d = c.config.data.datasets[0].data[c.config.data.datasets[0].data.length - 1] - c.config.data.datasets[1].data[c.config.data.datasets[1].data.length - 1],
        // position of last point in first dataset.
        xy0 = c.getDatasetMeta(0).data[c.getDatasetMeta(0).data.length - 1]._model,
        // position of last point in second dataset.
        xy1 = c.getDatasetMeta(1).data[c.getDatasetMeta(1).data.length - 1]._model;

      c.ctx.save();

      // draw the line.
      c.ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      c.ctx.beginPath();
      c.ctx.moveTo(xy0.x + 10, xy0.y);
      c.ctx.lineTo(xy0.x + 15, xy0.y); // draw the upper horizontal line.
      c.ctx.lineTo(xy0.x + 15, xy1.y); // draw the vertical line.
      c.ctx.lineTo(xy1.x + 10, xy1.y); // draw the lower horizontal line.
      c.ctx.stroke();

      // draw the text.
      c.ctx.font = '20px sans-serif';
      c.ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      c.ctx.fillText(
        d, // text
        c.chartArea.right + 25, // text x position
        xy0.y + ((xy1.y - xy0.y) / 2) // text y position
      );

      c.ctx.restore();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```